# Update Listbox via Range of Data from other Form not working?

Tags: c#

Im currently trying to get data from a richtextbox on Form2 and use it in Form1 to update a listbox and store the data for other use like saving to file.

The right data is present in UpdateData() => data when i loop through it via Console.WriteLine, but it wont get added to the ListBox.

Got no clue atm why and help would be appreciated

Code inside Form1 to update the existing listbox (lb_Items)

```
public void UpdateData()
    {

        data.AddRange(DataTransfer.PullData);
        UpdateItemBox(data);
    }

    private void UpdateItemBox(List<string> data)
    {
        lb_Items.DataSource = null;
        lb_Items.DataSource = data;
    }
```

Code inside Form2 to send data from a richtextbox (rtb_Data) and call the update function on Form1

```
  DataTransfer.PullData = rtb_Data.Lines;

  Form1 f1 = new Form1();
  f1.UpdateData();
```

DataTransfer Class

```
public static class DataTransfer
{
   public static string[] PullData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "Form1 f1 = new Form1();" creates a new instance of Form1 that is NEVER SEEN.  To update the EXISTING Form1 that is already on your screen, you need a reference to that instance of Form1.  Pass Form1 into Form2, for instance...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your form 1 creates your form 2, so you can make it get the lines

put this in form2

```
public List<string> GetRtbLines()
{
  return rtb_Data.Lines.ToList();
}
```

In whatever button you have in form1 that shows form2 (I imagine that form2 is basically just a dialog that appears so the user can paste lines in for use in the list of form 1) put

```
void SomeX_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
  var f2 = new Form2();
  f2.ShowDialog();
  lb_Items.DataSource = f2.GetRtbLines();
}
```

You can skip the rest of the code you have/datatransfer/update etc...

---

If form2 is some long lived thing that repeatedly pushes new data into the list/stays open alongside form1 you can instead:

Modify form2's constructor:

```
private Form1 _f1;
public Form2(Form1 f1){
  InitializeComponent();
  _f1 = f1;
}
```

Have some method in f1:

```
public void AddLines(string[] lines){
  (lb_Items.DataSource as List<string>).AddRange(lines);
}
```

Make sure the lb items has a list DataSource in the form1 constructor (so the above code doesn't crash)

```
lb_Items.DataSource = new List<string>();
```

And whenever you have new lines to add:

```
void AddLinesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
  _f1.AddLines(rtb_Data.Lines);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Tho my form2 need to be closed to make the items appear in the f1 list. Is there a way to update it without closing f2?

Comment: Second half of the answer? I've  put a horizontal line in to delineate; you do either one or the other, don't need to do both